# HiltViewModel in compose not working when testing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am trying to run a simple instrumented test on Android. My app runs fine and so does the following code when the viewmodel dependency `test` is commented out.

So I do not understand why I am getting "Cannot create an instance of class AskViewModel". I do not wish to inject this directly through the composable AskScreen. I have a feeling that this issue stems from the createComposeRule().

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class AskScreenTest {

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        composeRule.setContent { AskScreen() }
    }

    @Test
    fun openApp() {
        println("HELLO")
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class AskViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val test: PostQuestion,
): ViewModel() {
    
}
```

```
class PostQuestion @Inject constructor() {
    operator fun invoke() = Unit
}
```

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [RepositoryModule::class]
)
object RepositoryModuleTest {

    ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePostQuestion(): PostQuestion = PostQuestion()
}
```

```
@Composable
fun AskScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val viewModel: AskViewModel = hiltViewModel()
}
```

Comment: try removing RepositoryModuleTest file. since you have annotated PostQuestion with @inject. there is no need of Module setup.

Comment: I need this class since it provides many depencies for other tests. Also, I actually simplified the PostQuestion class constructor to try and find the underlying issue. It will eventually hold dependencies itself

Answer (score 0):

`createComposeRule` make a rule based on `ComponentActivity`, which is not annotated with `AndroidEntryPoint`. You need to define an Activity for testing unless you provide a view model instance to the composable function.

1. Define an HiltTestActivity with `AndroidEntryPoint` in the `app\src\debug` directory.

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltTestActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

2. Create an `AndroidManifest` in the directory and add the activity.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application>
        <activity android:name=".HiltTestActivity" android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

3. Use `createAndroidComposeRule` instead of `createComposeRule` in the test.

```kotlin
@get:Rule(order = 1)
val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<HiltTestActivity>()
```